# How do I level up skills in Wasteland?

Tags: wasteland

I am a big Wasteland fan from the days of yore.

However, now that I'm replaying the game, I can't figure out how to give my characters new skill points.

I know already that if, for example, I give my characters 1 point in Climbing, they'll get level 2 Climbing if I use the skill enough.

But when I radio in for levels (which I am getting) and put points in IQ/Skills, I don't get the option to spend my skill points.

I know there has to be a way to do this because I remember helicopter piloting skills and toaster repair in particular require a very high IQ that isn't available at all at level 1.

So, does anyone remember how this works? I've googled and everything I see is how to level up "quickly" not necessarily the basic mechanics of leveling.

Comment: Oops you have to visit a Library, of course, of course.

Comment: You can answer your own questions. You don't have to put it in a comment.

Comment: Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You can answer in 6 hours. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead.

Answer (score 4):

You have to visit a Library, which are only found in the later areas.